# How can I set mysql.rds_set_external_master to an RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-replication

I am attempting manual replication from one RDS MySql instance (named Original) to another RDS MySql instance (named New). I am essentially following the steps outlined here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-encrypt-instance-mysql-mariadb/

I am stuck around step 11-13. I ran `call mysql.rds_set_external_master` using the IP address that the read-replica of Original spit out. But when I subsequently run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;`, I see it is stuck at `Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master` and the logs show:

```
[ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicationuser@XXX.XX.X.XX:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1, Error_code: MY-002003
```

I double-checked the security group and VPC settings and it's all in order.

[AWS documentation on rds_set_external_master](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html) does not mention being able to set an RDS instance as a replication master. It states specifically that it `Configures a MySQL DB instance to be a Read Replica of an instance of MySQL running external to Amazon RDS`

I am beginning to think the first link is asking us to do the impossible...

Comment: This works fine.  You have overlooked something... it's a matter of figuring out what that is.  Is the IP address you're using to configure the "external master" a public or private IP?  Are these two in the same VPC?  Have you tried allowing traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 on the "Original" master's security group?

Comment: It's likely a private IP assigned by AWS. I've tried both that IP and the public DNS endpoint and both result in the same error. The two RDS instances are part of the same VPC and are assigned the same security group. This security group allows all inbound and outbound traffic to others in the same security group.

Comment: setting ` 0.0.0.0/0 ` in my master sg worked for me. Although i already had an entry to allow anything from within the vpc `10.0.0.0/16`. They are both public. Why did ` 0.0.0.0/0 ` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED IT.

You need to use the **internal, private IP for your master instance**.

1. Using an ec2 instance in the same region, run

   `dig <your-master-instance>.rds.amazonaws.com`

   (If you don't have dig, you can also use nslookup.)
2. Get the resulting INTERNAL IP, eg 172.31.123.123
3. Use that IP when calling

   `mysql.rds_set_external_master(...)`

   ...on the new instance.

Note that you should not generally connect to RDS instances using their IPs, since the IP is dynamic and can change with auto version upgrade, etc.

However, in this case, the internal IP works while hostname does not. Also, since this is an upgrade procedure, the new instance only needs to be replicating the host for a few hours at most: using the internal IP should be fine.

Shout-out to Aryan at AWS enterprise support.

Comment: Using the IP address did not fix it for me. Credentials are correct. Security groups are correct. Verified connectivity between RDS instances by launching an instance in that subnet. No dice :/

Comment: What's in the error log or Last_IO_Error column of replication info, Dennis?

Comment: @Dennis what came of this?

Comment: @Kay I have no idea. I do not know why I am tagged here. The OP nor the comment you're replying to is mine (even though it somehow shows my name). Unless I have severe Alzheimers.

Comment: @Dennis I apologise but the first comment on this post for me is by "Dennis" and both your nrew comment and that comment in Mar 14 2020 leads to the same  account. users/2695716/dennis

Comment: @Kay I know. There's nothing to apologise for. I'm equally confused.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to set the master to a read-only replica, changing it to the master worked with the DNS